# Understand Python for Towers of Hanoi

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I understand the thinking of how to solve Hanoi with Python recursion, but I don’t understand how we could write this Python language:

```
def hanoi(n,x,y,z):
    if n == 1:
        print(x, ' --> ',z)
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,x,z,y)
        print(x, ' --> ',z)
        hanoi(n-1,y,x,z)
hanoi(2,'SRC','TMP','TAG')
```

if the first step is to put (x-1) dishes from source to tmp, why we write hanoi(n-1,z,y) ? why we switch z and y?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are understanding the variables wrong:

- `n` is the number of disks
- `x` is the first pole
- `y` is the pole used for transferring
- `z` is the pole for the destination of the transferred disk

Since we want to solve `hanoi(n, x, y, z)`, we do as follows:

- If there's only 1 disk to move, we're done (aka the `n==1` bit)
- Otherwise we have to move the disk from the source pole (`x`) to the final pole (`z`) using the temporary pole (`y`)

We do this by moving `n-1` disks from `x` to `y` using `z` (aka `hanoi(n-1, x, z, y)`), then moving the last disk to `z`, then moving all remaining disks (which are on `y`) onto `z` (the final pole) with `hanoi(n-1, y, x, z)`

---

Here's a gif to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your explanation! Sorry, I am a bit dump. about this one" moving n-1 disks from x to y using z (aka hanoi(n-1, x, z, y))".  when we write n-1,x,z,y. how Python know what we mean is to using z to move x to y?

Comment: This is one of the beautiful things about programming: a language doesn't inherently "know" anything. We design algorithms that take inputs and produce outputs, and it is up to us (the programmers/users) to apply any sort of meaning to it. We decided that hanoi(n-1, x, z, y) would represent moving n-1 disks from x to y using z, not Python.